# How can I make my logo responsive at the top of my website?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have created a loader and logo for my website. However, I have an issue with my logo, which is at the top of the website. The logo is not responsive. I would like my logo to be at the top middle of my website, but, when someone goes to view it on their window screen, the logo moves to somewhere other than the middle. I have tried adding a display: flex; and justify content; on my load class, but it does not work and the 3D effect goes away. How can I prevent the logo from moving and let it stay in the top middle regardless of someone's window size? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="load">
    <p id = "spinner">M</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="loader">
          <div class="loader">
            <div class="loader">
              <div class="loader">
                <div class="loader">
                  <div class="loader">
                    <div class="loader">
                      <div class="loader">
                        <div class="loader">
                          <div class="loader">
                            <div class="loader">
                              <div class="loader">
                                <div class="loader">
                                  <div class="loader">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    body{
    background: #21312F;
}
 
.container{
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 20%;
    left: 43%;
}
 
.loader{
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 2.5%;
    border-top: 3px solid #49D49F;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6542;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: 30s rotate linear infinite;
}

.load {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #21312F;
  }

 
@keyframes rotate{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(810deg);
    }
}
 

 
#spinner{
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    animation-name: spin, depth;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: -40px;
    color: #49D49F;
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
 
 
#spinner::before, #spinner::after{
    content: "M";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotateY(0.5deg);
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    color: #FF6542;
}
 
#spinner::after{
    
    transform: rotateY(-0.5deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
 
}
 
@keyframes spin{
    from{
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to{
        transform: rotateY(-360deg)
    }
}
 
@keyframes depth {
    0% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
    25% { text-shadow: 1px 0 black, 2px 0 black, 3px 0 black, 4px 0 black, 5px 0 black, 6px 0 black; }
    50% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
    75% { text-shadow: -1px 0 black, -2px 0 black, -3px 0 black, -4px 0 black, -5px 0 black, -6px 0 black; }
    100% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
  }
```

Comment: Cool animation!

Comment: This animation motion is jarring to me and seems like a seizure risk :/ 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Seizure_disorders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but do you want like this? :

```css
body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
        background: #21312F;
    }
    
    .container{
        position: absolute;
        height: 400px;
        width: 200px;
        top: 20%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    
    .loader{
        height: 95%;
        width: 95%;
        margin: 2.5%;
        border-top: 3px solid #49D49F;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6542;
        border-radius: 50%;
        animation: 30s rotate linear infinite;
    }

    .load {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 99;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #21312F;
      }

    
    @keyframes rotate{
        0%{
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%{
            transform: rotate(810deg);
        }
    }
    

    
    #spinner{
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        animation-name: spin, depth;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        color: #49D49F;
        font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    
    #spinner::before, #spinner::after{
        content: "M";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        transform: rotateY(0.5deg);
        transform-origin: 0 50%;
        color: #FF6542;
    }
    
    #spinner::after{
        
        transform: rotateY(-0.5deg);
        transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    
    }
    
    @keyframes spin{
        from{
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
        to{
            transform: rotateY(-360deg)
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes depth {
        0% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
        25% { text-shadow: 1px 0 black, 2px 0 black, 3px 0 black, 4px 0 black, 5px 0 black, 6px 0 black; }
        50% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
        75% { text-shadow: -1px 0 black, -2px 0 black, -3px 0 black, -4px 0 black, -5px 0 black, -6px 0 black; }
        100% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
      }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="load">
    <p id = "spinner">M</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="loader">
          <div class="loader">
            <div class="loader">
              <div class="loader">
                <div class="loader">
                  <div class="loader">
                    <div class="loader">
                      <div class="loader">
                        <div class="loader">
                          <div class="loader">
                            <div class="loader">
                              <div class="loader">
                                <div class="loader">
                                  <div class="loader">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, this what I needed. Thank you!